# How do I programmatically set Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS on a .NET web service?

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, iis-6, integrated

I have a web service project that needs to be set to use Integrated Windows Authentication after installation. Normally, I would install the web service, then manually go to IIS and make sure the box is checked for Integrated Windows Authentication. There has to be a way to do this through code. I have looked up on using the Installer class. It looks like this is something I could use, but I have not found anything on setting properties programmatically in IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String applicationPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", _server.Sites["Default Web Site"].Name, "AppName");

Configuration config = _server.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

ConfigurationSection anonymousAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", applicationPath);

anonymousAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = false;

ConfigurationSection windowsAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication", applicationPath);

windowsAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = true;

_server.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: I have "Cannot access protected internal indexer 'this' here" message

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy). This technology is designed by MS to, umm, deploy web apps. ;-)